# $\overline A + \overline B \subset \overline{A + B}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I already show this but I cannot find an example for a strict inclusion.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Suppose $A = (0,2), B = (1,3)$

Comment: @DougM this is example for equality I want a example for strict inclusion

Comment: Does $+$ mean intersection, which is usually denoted as $\cap$?

Comment: @KevinLong it is addition

Comment: Then $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$? Common set operations include union and intersection. Something like addition needs to be defined.

Comment: @KevinLong  yes it is addition like you defined

Comment: It is called the Minkowski sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume we are talking about subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (this has to be specified since there are topological groups where the equality always holds, e.g. with discrete topology). In that case let

$$A=\{n\ |\ n=2,3,4,\ldots\}$$
$$B=\big\{-n+\frac{1}{n}\ \big|\ n=2,3,4,\ldots\big\}$$

They are both closed subsets so $\overline{A}=A$ and $\overline{B}=B$.

Note that $0\in\overline{A+B}$ while $0\not\in A+B$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $A$ and $B$ are *bounded* subsets of $\Bbb R^d$, then $\overline A + \overline B = \overline{A+B}$.